# CSS Intellisense in MVC 4 has stopped working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have and MVC 4 web app I am designing.

I recently added the bootstrap files to the application and I was happily working away creating cool looking pages with fully working Intellisense including CSS classes.

Then last night I notice the intellisense wasn't working and the only changes I'd made were minor ones to the _layout view.  I tried undoing my changes but this didn't reverse the problem.

I must say Intellisense is working for everything else, it only stopped for CSS Classes.

I have googled away on this and tried almost all the "solutions" I've found.

- Renaming or deleting the 10.0 folder from the "%AppData%....\Visual Studio" folder.
- Deleting the 11.0\ReflectedSchemas folder
- Resetting all the Visual Studio settings
- Installing Web Essentials

I've also tried the following to test the problem further

- Opened a different MVC 4 project

  - Demonstrated the same problem despite not being edited for some time and was previously working
- Created a new MVC 4 project

  - Same problem
- Created a new Web Forms application

  - CSS Intellisense worked perfectly in this application.

So it seems this is afflicting only MVC applications and for what I can discern as no apparent reason.

Help... I miss my intellisense.

Comment: Update web-essentials maybe?

Comment: Just tried that too Alex, sorry, it didn't work either.